# Creating an audio streaming platform from scratch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, audio, audio-streaming, web-development-server

I am trying to create an on-demand audio streaming platform (similar to Spotify) from scratch. It will have 1000 users (I am optimizing for time to build, not scalability as of right now).
I want to use web-based technologies ( I am experienced with React/Redux/Node). Could I get some advice on the architecture (what technologies I should use for the project)?

Here are things I need help with

1. **What Storage service I should use for my music files (my song catalog is about 50000)**
2. **How to stream music from the storage service to each user**
3. **What server protocol I should use (RTMP/WebRTC/RTS)**
4. **(Optional) How to store data in cache to reduce buffer**

I know this is a huge ask so thank you guys for your help in advance

Comment: I have an audio-focused content management system that you can use to implement such a site.  It supports a large catalog, has been designed for flexibility, and gives you a multitude of options for scaling.  If you are interested in jumpstarting your project, please contact me at brad@audiopump.co.

Answer (score 6):

> What Storage service I should use for my music files (my song catalog is about 50000)

S3 (or equivalent).

Audio files fit this use case precisely, and you're already using AWS.  If you find the cost too high, there are compatible services that are more affordable, all the way down to DIY on Minio.

> How to stream music from the storage service to each user

Use a CDN (or multiple CDNs) to optimize delivery and keep the latency low.  CDNs are also better at spoon-feeding slow clients.

> What server protocol I should use (RTMP/WebRTC/RTS)

Normal HTTP!  That's all you need, and that's all that's been necessary for decades for this use case.

RTMP is a dead protocol, only supported by Flash on the client side.  Its usage today is limited to sending source streams from video encoders, and even that is well on its way out the door.

WebRTC is intended for low latency connections, like voice calls and video chat.  This is not something that matters in a unidirectional stream.  You actually want a robust streaming mechanism... not one that drops audio like a cell phone to keep up to realtime.

RTSP is not something you can use in a browser, and is overly complex for what you need.

Just a simple HTTP service is sufficient.  Your servers should support ranged requests so that the browser can lose a connection and still pick up right where they left off, without the listener even knowing.  (All CDNs support this, as does any properly configured web server.)

> (Optional) How to store data in cache to reduce buffer

CDNs will generally improve performance of the initial connect and load.  I also recommend pre-loading the next track to be played in the list so that you can start it immediately.  In most browsers, you can actually start the next track at the tail end of the previous track for a smooth transition.